# SSRS Native Mode Report Manager URL Root Instead of /Reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Trying to figure out a way to set the Report Manager URL to / instead of /Reports. Tried doing this in the Reporting Services Configuration Manager without success. It didn't seem to like using the root URL.

Does anyone know if this can be done?

Or potentially redirect the / URL to /Reports behind the scenes.

Working in SQL Server 2012 SP2.

Comment: did you check [this?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630447.aspx) `The only difference is the virtual directory name (in this case, it is reports but you can configure it to use whatever name that you want)`

Comment: yes. tried changing it to "whatever i want" which was nothing and it didn't work. I think it is expecting a word for the path instead of the root